# A religious riddle ... or not

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> The serpent slithered through the grass,
>   First to Eve, the mistress of Eden,
>   And made her cross with what it told.
>
> When first Adam heard of what had occurred,
>   "You silly hen!" he chided his wife.
>   But all too late; 'twas the end of the end.
>
> As though with the prick of a thorn,
>   Knowledge finally came to them both.
>
> Clearly now they could see,
>   With the eyes God had made them,
>   That at last they'd lost
>   And this was their final day.

**What is this poem really referring to?**

Comment: Are the male and female characters referring to actual male and female characters?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answer:

> Sex and the City

---

The serpent slithered through the grass,

> S (looks like a snake)

First to Eve, the mistress of Eden,

> E (first letter of Eve)

And made her cross with what it told.

> X (a cross)

When first Adam heard of what had occurred,

> A (first letter of Adam)

"You silly hen!" he chided his wife.

> N (sounds like "hen")

But all too late; 'twas the end of the end.

> D (last letter of "the end")

As though with the prick of a thorn,

> TH (letter "thorn")

Knowledge finally came to them both.

> E (last letter of "knowledge")

Clearly now they could see,

> C (sounds like "see")

With the eyes God had made them,

> I (sounds like "eye")

That at last they'd lost

> T (last letter of "that")

And this was their final day.

> Y (last letter of "day")

Comment: You are fast, sir! How did you come up with this - what gave it away?

Comment: @randal'thor "First" and "last"/"final" made me think of taking the first and last letters of the neighboring words, and then "see" and "eyes" stood out as homophones for letters. I guessed the rest from there.